# Weird caret behavior when using selection on word-wrap boundary in Firefox

Tags: firefox, dom, range, selection, word-wrap

I'd like to make use of selection object that can be retrieved from window.getSelection().
So my initial attempt is to check whether a returned range from getRangeAt() can be applied back to the selection using addRange().

See the jsfiddle below, which does nothing but tries to save the range from getSelection() and restore it without altering anything else.

```
var selection = window.getSelection()

$('#textfield').keyup(function() {
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
  selection.removeAllRanges()
  selection.addRange(range)
})
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWqvU/1)

It initially seems OK and works naturally, but when you type in a long line, resulting in a word-wrap, left arrow key near the wrapped line does not move the caret properly to the previous line, but bounces back.

```
aaaaaa
^aaaaaa
(original caret(^) at end of the second line)

aaaaa^
aaaaa
(moved the caret by pressing left arrow key)

aaaaa
^aaaaa
(the caret immediately bounced back to the second line)
```

This effect can be shown in Firefox (mine is FF 16).

Is this a known bug? Or is there anything I've misused? It seems Chrome works without the problem.